# JS does not call different package feature file. But it is taking, if you give from java class location

Tags: karate

|
|------parant
|       |
|       |-parent.feature
|       |-parent.java
|
|-------child
          |
          |-child.feature
          |-child.js

if i run test case from parent.java,
    parent.feature calls child.js. child.js calls child.feature means it does not take **read('child.feature')**. i have to give like **read('../child/child.feature')**. my issue is i have child.js and child.feature in same place. why i have to give the path from java class like '../child/child.feature' ?

Answer (score 0):

Karate discourages you from making too many calls. You are advised to stick to only one or 2 levels of feature re-use. Karate always uses the directory of the "main" (entry-point) feature as the "working directory". This is so that all files (e.g. JSON, XML) can be read relative to that path.

If you really need to do this gymnastics - use `read('classpath:child.feature')` and manage your files that way.